# 403 forbidden error on submission data from form

Tags: php, forms

Here is my code:

It works fine in `localhost` using `xampp` but when I try to submit data from my website it gives **error as**

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /new/career-cms/course_detail.php
>   on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

```
 <?php

if($_POST)
{
$menu_id = $_POST['menu_bar'];
$sub_menu_id = $_POST['sub_menu'];
$course_id = $_POST['courses'];


$time_format =$_POST['time_format'];
$Day = $_POST['DayWeek'];
$Hours = $_POST['HoursDay'];
$Class_Time_1st = $_POST['Class_Time_1st'];
$course_tags = $_POST['course_tags'];
$course_instructors = $_POST['instructors'];
$instructors = implode(" " , $course_instructors);
$Course_Discription = $_POST['Course_Discription'];
$Course_Outline = $_POST['Course_Outline'];


 $myClassObj->insert("course_detail",array("menu_bar_id"=>"$menu_id","sub_menu_bar_id"=>"$sub_menu_id","courses_id"=>"$course_id","time_format"=>"$time_format" , "DayWeek"=>"$Day" ,"HoursDay"=>"$Hours" , "Class_Time_1st"=>"$Class_Time_1st" , "Course_Discription"=>"$Course_Discription", "Course_Outline"=>"$Course_Outline", "course_tag"=>"$course_tags", " instructors"=>"$instructors"));


?>


 <div class="inserted wow bounceInLeft" >
<p align="center"> <strong>Inserted</strong> </p>
 </div>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Comment: If you are using Linux server :
First check that you have the right to read the file, chmod 655 /new/career-cms/course_detail.php
if it is still not working, look for the .htaccess file and be sure the file can be read

Comment: but how can i check..?

Comment: What kind of server do you have ? Ubuntu, Fedora, Debian, Windows ? Look at this to know : [http://whatsmyos.com/](http://whatsmyos.com/)

Comment: Did you use Filezilla to upload the files ?
There is a way to see permissions on filezilla

Comment: yes i used filezilla

Comment: please tell me how is it possible to get rid of this error

Comment: it works fine with simple text. but when i used to post html tags it gives error

Comment: It s really weird, how are you calling the POST ?